# How to go back to DCHP after setting up static IP?

Tags: networking

My daughter has a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. A while back I used some tutorial I found to set a static IP for her because she was having internet problems.  Recently we changed up our home network, and we have a different subnet.

How do I get rid of the static IP?  I have a lot of android & windows experience but for anything Linux related I need every step spelled out for me.

Comment: What version of Raspbian are you using Stretch, Jessie or Wheezy? The contents of /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/dhcpcd.conf  would help give an answer too

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the reasons for NOT setting static IP addesses.

You have not told us which version of Raspbian, but it is probably Jessie.

There are 2 common methods of setting static IP addess, they are described in [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

If you reverse the process you should be able to restore normal operation.

It is likely you modified `/etc/network/interfaces`, and the default contents for Jessie and Stretch are listed in the link.